# If mapped item is null or empty use alternative value by concat of 2 other properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

This is my code for collating items in preparation for submission to a RESTful API:

```
let mergeLinesData = this.incomingStepsData.map((item) => ({
    dataStepId: _.get(item, 'stepId'),
    dataStepName: _.get(item, 'stepName'),
    name: _.get(item, 'itemName')
}));
```

However some users may not have yet defined a name so I would like to fall back and set a default value for name at this point.

How can I provide a default value as I would with javascript variables such as

```
fruit = fruit || "strawberry";
```

And how can that default value be a concatenation of `dataStepName + "-" + dataStepId`?

Comment: Are you using `lodash`? Then in `get` you can pass a third argument which is a default value.

Comment: hi the project does use lodash though I havent experience with this - could you provide example of third argument and how it could concat based on those 2 vals which will always be available? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to do it with js , rather than using lodash for it. You can use destructuring.

```
let mergeLinesData = this.incomingStepsData.map(({stepId, stepName, itemName}) => ({
    dataStepId: stepId,
    dataStepName: stepName
    name: itemName || `${stepName}-${stepId}`
}));
```

Comment: Thanks this is the route I had in mind and is working as expected! Thanks Komal

Answer (score 4):

Just add a conditional statement to your code like in your example:

```
name: _.get(item, "itemName") || `${dataStepName}-${dataStepId}`)
```

Alternatively, use the third parameter of `_.get()`:

```
name: _.get(item, "itemName", `${dataStepName}-${dataStepId}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names), and [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```js
const incomingStepsData = [{ stepId: 1, stepName: 'step1', name: 'name1' }, { stepId: 2, stepName: 'step2' }];

const mergeLinesData = incomingStepsData.map(({
  stepId: dataStepId,
  stepName: dataStepName,
  name: itemName = `${dataStepName}-${dataStepId}`
}) => ({
    dataStepId,
    dataStepName,
    itemName
}));

console.log(mergeLinesData);
```